# Resample one year down to one average day

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have data from one year with hourly time steps. The data looks like this:

```
2020-01-01 01:00:00  3
2020-01-01 02:00:00  4
2020-01-01 03:00:00  2
2020-01-01 04:00:00  3
2020-01-01 05:00:00  6
2020-01-01 06:00:00  8
2020-01-01 07:00:00  5
2020-01-01 08:00:00  9
...
2020-12-31 20:00:00  8
2020-12-31 21:00:00  4
2020-12-31 22:00:00  7
2020-12-31 23:00:00  2
```

From this data I would like to determine the average day for the year. Result

01:00:00  --> mean of all values from 1 o'clock
02:00:00  --> mean of all values from 2 o'clock
...

Comment: Can you please mention the second column is the column on which you are calculating "average day of the year"? It would be better, If you could provide header for both columns and later frame the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### new answer:

If you want the average value per hour:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.hour)['value'].mean()
```

output:

```
hour value
1     3
2     4
3     2
4     3
5     6
6     8
7     5
8     9
20    8
21    4
22    7
23    2
```

*NB. the output is the same as input here as there is not enough data to compute the mean*

#### old answer:

Your question is not entirely clear, I imagine you want the average value *per day*. I further assume you have two columns named "date" and "value":

```
                   date  value
0   2020-01-01 01:00:00      3
1   2020-01-01 02:00:00      4
2   2020-01-01 03:00:00      2
3   2020-01-01 04:00:00      3
4   2020-01-01 05:00:00      6
5   2020-01-01 06:00:00      8
6   2020-01-01 07:00:00      5
7   2020-01-01 08:00:00      9
8   2020-12-31 20:00:00      8
9   2020-12-31 21:00:00      4
10  2020-12-31 22:00:00      7
11  2020-12-31 23:00:00      2
```

You can convert to `datetime` type, use `dt.floor` to floor to the day and `groupby` the floored value to take the mean:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('d'))['value'].mean()
```

output:

```
2020-01-01    5.00
2020-12-31    5.25
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but what I need is the average day for the year on an hourly basis. The result should have a value for each hour as an average of the values of the year

Comment: @Elefant can you check the updated answer?

Comment: Hi again, is there any way to do the same thing as above but instead of grouping it by hour I want to group it by the quarter hour. Of course I have the data with dates and in quarter hour timesteps.